# What sort of "invitation" do I need for a Belarusian visa?

Tags: visas, invitation-letters, belarus, couchsurfing

I would like to visit Belarus.  To apply for a Belarusian visa, one needs an "invitation", which is usually provided by a hotel or travel agency.  However, I would like to travel independently, staying with CouchSurfing hosts.

Is it possible to do this?

Here's the [Belarusian visa application form](http://www.belarussianvisa.com/belarus-visa-forms/english.pdf).  Boxes 21 and 22 concern the invitation.

Comment: Which citizenship do you apply with? For some countries it's different.

Comment: For which countries is it different?

Comment: "To get a short-term visa for private purposes (visiting Belarusian relatives, friends, other private matters) with a validity of 30 days, maximum for 1-, 2- or multiple entries for citizens of the EU as well as nationals of several other countries, such as Australia, Andorra, Argentina, Bahrain, Brazil, Canada, Croatia, Chili, Island, Israel, Norway, Swiss Confederation, Republic of Korea, New Zealand, Uruguay, Republic of South Africa and Japan, no visa support documents shall be required (letter of invitation etc. documents)." http://wikitravel.org/en/Belarus

Comment: I'm curious what made you pick the destination?

Comment: @LexVjatkin I also read that WikiTravel page, however the correctness of that statement is disputed on the Talk page.  I'd like to have a more authoritative source.

Comment: Here is "more authoritative source": [Belarus embassy in Germany](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fgermany.mfa.gov.by%2Fru%2Fkonsul%2Fvisa%2Fprivatreise) See last paragraph. ".. provide visa support documents is not required". And yes, in germany you need some extra statement from belarus citizen. But it's different for each country. Ask your embassy about that.

Answer (score 6):

If you search for "Belarus invitation" you can find a slew of formal letters that you will need to obtain a visa.

If you are going as a tourist then [this particular letter](http://www.belvisa.com/InvitationLetterBelarusian.htm) is for you.  There is also a post from one of the [travel agencies](http://www.minskguide.travel/belarus_travel_tips/belarus_immigration/letter_of_invitation_to_belarus.html) in Belarus about who has to send you one of these letters if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

As of about two weeks ago, citizens of 80 countries had the visa requirements waived if and only if the arrive at Minsk airport on an international flight (except Russia). They are allowed to stay for up to 5 days.

This came in as I was getting documents together for my trip in May!

https://twitter.com/BelarusMID/status/818459592116043778